# Devise - limit registrations by using the password reset mechanism?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I'm looking for a way to allow private registrations, or registrations that require manual approval. The latter can be done using the strategy as described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in), but I figure the former method might be more convenient if I could somehow take advantage of the password reset module to simplify the process (send an email with a one-time use token but for the purpose of account creation). Has anyone attempted anything like this, or possibly have a better strategy that makes greater use of existing components in devise?

possibly related: [Ruby on rails: Devise, want to add invite code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704837/ruby-on-rails-devise-want-to-add-invite-code)

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit I am not a big fan of using features in a framework that are designed for other uses to accomplish some other goal.

What I usually do when I want a private Sign-Up where you have to be invited to the App is to simply put the user creation/registration inside the Application. After all Devise is just an authentication mechanism ontop of the `User` model.

So in my current app for example there is a explicit way inside the app for existing users to invite a friend.
The inviting User has a form that creates an entry in the Users table for the new guy with his email address and a field that tells me if the user has finished his registration. I create a little Token that also gets saved to the Database (`SecureRandom.hex(8)` is a nice way to create such Tokens). 
The system shoots the new guy a email telling him where to sign up (with a URL that contains the token), and the sign up is just a form that sets password and additional fields.

All of this is no real magic in Rails, it's all in all 2 controller actions, 2 views and 1 mailer to accomplish it and you are in no way constrained by any API Devise is or is not giving you.

I only had to make sure Devise won't authenticate Users that have not yet redeemed their invitation token but that's it then.

Sure not having to write the sign up view is convenient, but especially when you are dealing with partial information (the inviting User in my case has to fill in some information about the new user already) that gets only complemented by the new user it's quite convenient to just have regular forms where you can do anything with them.

Unless someone writes a Gem that extends Devise to do exactly this, I think I'll stick to this approach.

Comment: I appreciate the input, just wanted to make sure I'm not expending too much time to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I think this is a perfect spot for a gem to extend Devise so not everyone has to re-invent the wheel .. I'll have a look to see if that's feasable to extract the relevant info into a Gem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a third strategy - I could simply lock new accounts (lockable, before_create filter) and provide a manual unlock facility.